# Is there any way I can count the number of layers in a model, i.e., numerical answer?

Tags: python, loops, tensorflow, keras

Consider the following model

```
def create_model():
  x_1=tf.Variable(24)
  bias_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.HeNormal()
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5),  input_shape=(28,28,1),activation="relu", name='conv2d_1', use_bias=True,bias_initializer=bias_initializer))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation="relu",name='conv2d_2',  use_bias=True,bias_initializer=bias_initializer))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(120, name='dense_1',activation="relu", use_bias=True,bias_initializer=bias_initializer),)
  model.add(Dense(10, name='dense_2', activation="softmax", use_bias=True,bias_initializer=bias_initializer),)
```

I can extract summary of the model instance but is there any method that can give/count the number of layers (with trainable parameters)?
For example, the above posted model has 4 layers with trainable parameters.

Comment: Perhaps `len([L for L in model.layers if L.trainable])`. However, when I run your code, it looks like all the layers initialized here are trainable.

Comment: Thanks. So is there any way I can get the number of Conv2d and Dense layers in a model?

Comment: First of all, quick update: `len([L for L in model.layers if L.trainable_weights])` gives the correct answer of 4

Comment: You could also detect conv2d and dense layers as follows: `len([L for L in model.layers if 'conv2d' in L.name or 'dense' in L.name])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model.trainable_weights` gives a list of all the trainable weights. Weights and biases are considered independently, so you need to take unique count of the total number of weights

```
np.unique([i.name.split('/')[0] for i in model.trainable_weights])
>>>
array(['conv2d_1', 'conv2d_2', 'dense_1', 'dense_2'], dtype='<U8')

len(np.unique([i.name.split('/')[0] for i in model.trainable_weights]))
>>>
4
```

Comment: This is not such a good idea because it relies on layer names, which you can overwrite with something else.

Comment: Even if you don’t name the layers, the result for number of layers would remain the same. The first part is in case you want the names of the layers.